# How did Euler prove the partial fraction expansion of the cotangent function: $\pi\cot(\pi z)=\frac1z+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\frac1{z-k}+\frac1{z+k})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, reference-request, math-history, partial-fractions

As far as we know, Euler was the first to prove $$ \pi \cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{z-k} + \frac{1}{z+k} \right).$$ I've seen several modern proofs of it and they all seem to rely either on the [Herglotz trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581162/how-does-the-herglotz-trick-work) or on the residue theorem. I recon Euler had neither nor at his disposal, so how did he prove it?

**Added**: Did Euler prove it for complex $z$ or just reals?

Comment: You may wish to read Euler's original work "Intoduction in Analysin Infinitorum", §178.  In Latin: https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1100&context=euler-works. and in an english translation http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/introductiontoanalysisvol1.htm. Look for chapter 9 (product formula for $\sin$) and 10 (proof of series for $\cot$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, Euler just considered the logarithmic derivative ($\frac{d}{dz}\log(\cdot)$) of both sides of
$$ \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
to derive the above identity, disregarding possible convergence issues. $(1)$ was well-known to him, and the key for his solution of the [Basel problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2). The possibility to apply the logarithmic derivative to both sides of $(1)$ follows from the whole Mittag-Leffler/Weierstrass products machinery.

It is possible to prove $(1)$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$ (together with its uniform convergence over any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$) by avoiding complex analysis, just exploiting the properties of [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html), but I am not so sure that Euler was aware of that (also because Chebyshev came about 100 years later than Euler).

Answer (score 4):

Euler did have access to the infinite product representation of the sine function

$$\sin(\pi z)=\pi z\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d \log(\sin(\pi z))}{dz}&=\pi \cot(\pi z)\\\\
&=\frac1z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2z}{z^2-n^2}\\\\
&=\frac1z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac{1}{z+n}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Yes, but how do we justify that logarithm and infinite product can be interchanged?

Comment: @aiyy The logarithm is a continuous function on the positive reals.  Can you show that if $a_k\to a$ that $\log\left(a_k\right)\to\log(a)$?