# The Finite Sum $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(3r-2)(3r+2)}$ and failure to Telescope

Tags: summation, telescopic-series

I'm interested in when the partial fraction method of trying to get a series to telescope fails, and have alighted upon the interesting example of,

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(3r-2)(3r+2)}$$
The standard method of tackling this would be to use partial fractions to get,
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(3r-2)(3r+2)}=\frac{1}{4}\big(\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3r-2}-\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3r+2}\big)$$
and then look at the fractions generated by this alternative representation of the sum,
$$=\frac{1}{4}\big(\big(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{5}\big)+\big(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}\big)+\big(\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}\big)+\big(\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{14}\big)+...+\big(\frac{1}{3n-2}-\frac{1}{3n+2}\big)\big)$$
To me, this does not obviously telescope.

Questions

1. I am was wondering if anyone can see a way to get this to telescope.
2. Failing that, have a nice explanation of why it will not telescope.
3. Is there a way of evaluating the sum to $n$ terms via a different approach ?

An Observation

In exploring the series I put it into Wolfram Alpha which reported that the series is convergent and that,
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3r-2)(3r+2)}=\frac{1}{72}\big(2\sqrt{3}\pi+9\big)$$

Given the famous Basel problem for the sum of reciprocals of squares, the appearance of $\pi$ is not, perhaps, a surprise.

Comment: It never telescopes, because $3r+2\ne3s-2$.

Comment: *Welcome back to the site !*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3r-2)(3r+2)}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(9r^2-4)}=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^2-(\frac{2}{3})^2}$$
then use the
$$\frac{1-\pi*x\cot\pi x}{2x^2}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^2-x^2}$$
and put $x=\frac{2}{3}$

so the sum will be
$$\frac{9+2\sqrt{3}\pi}{72}$$

Comment: The no nonsense, convert it into a standard form with a known result approach - Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Here's another answer: it's known that $$1+2x^2\sum_{v=1}^{\infty}\frac1{x^2-v^2} = \pi x\cot(\pi x)$$
See here [How did Euler prove the partial fraction expansion of the cotangent function: $\pi\cot(\pi z)=\frac1z+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(\frac1{z-k}+\frac1{z+k})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849878/how-did-euler-prove-the-partial-fraction-expansion-of-the-cotangent-function) for example.
Setting $x=2/3$ gives $$1+2\sum_{v=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1{3v+2}-\frac1{3v-2}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{3}\cot(\frac{2\pi}{3})=\frac{-2\pi\sqrt3}{9}$$, from which, after simple calculations:$$1/4\sum_{v=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac1{3v-2}-\frac1{3v+2}\right)=\frac{2\pi \sqrt3+9}{72}$$

Comment: Very succinct and tidy answer and I appreciate you spelling out the connection to Euler. Thank you !

Comment: clever connection to $\cot$ series (+1)

Answer (score 2):

We can write the sum as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r = 1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{(3r-2)(3r+2)} &= \dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}\left[\dfrac{1}{(3r-2)} - \dfrac{1}{(3r+2)}\right]
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}(x^{3r-3}-x^{3r+1})\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}(x^{3r-3}-x^{3r+1})\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(1-x^4)-(x^{3n}-x^{3n+4})}{1-x^3}\,dx
\\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x^3}\,dx - \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}x^{3n}\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x^3}\,dx.
\end{align*}

You can easily  show that $$0 \le \int_{0}^{1}x^{3n}\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x^3}\,dx \le \int_{0}^{1}x^{3n}\sup_{x \in [0,1]}\left[\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x^3}\right]\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{4}{3}x^{3n}\,dx = \dfrac{4}{3(3n+1)}$$ for all integers $n \ge 0$, and thus, $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{3n}\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x^3}\,dx \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty.$$

Therefore, $$\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(3r-2)(3r+2)} = \dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x^3}\,dx = \dfrac{9+2\pi\sqrt{3}}{72},$$ which can be easily evaluated using partial fractions.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you've made with this. Thanks for such a full answer.

Comment: (+1) It's nice to see you are back.  I hope you're well and staying safe and healthy.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the infinite series: as you have already found,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(3r-2)(3r+2)} &= \frac{1}{4}\bigg(\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3r-2}-\Big(\sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{3r+2} - \frac12 \Big)\bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\bigg(\frac12+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\chi_{-3}(n)}n \bigg),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } n\equiv1\pmod3, \\
-1, &\text{if } n\equiv2\pmod3, \\
0, &\text{if } 3\mid n
\end{cases}
is the nonprincipal Dirichlet character of conductor $3$. The infinite series is a well-known constant
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\chi_{-3}(n)}n = L(1,\chi_{-3}) = \frac\pi{3\sqrt3},
$$
which recovers your formula (with a sign typo corrected).

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer which ties in beautifully with what I know on Dirichlet characters. Although I was more interested in checking out the finite sum I appreciate the connection your answer makes to modern analytic Number Theory.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Digamma function satisfies the functional equation
$$
\Delta \psi (z) = \psi (z + 1) - \psi (z) = {1 \over z}
$$
Then its [Anti-Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum) is
$$
\psi (z) = \Delta ^{\, - 1} {1 \over z} = \sum\nolimits_{\;z}^{} {{1 \over z}} 
$$

Using this concept, the sum is defined also for real (and in this case also complex) lower and upper bound, as
$$
\sum\nolimits_{\;z = a}^{\;b} {{1 \over z}}  = \psi (b) - \psi (a)
$$

So your sum gets converted into the Anti-Delta concept as follows
$$
\eqalign{
  & {1 \over 4}\left( {\sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {{1 \over {3r - 2}}}  - \sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {{1 \over {3r + 2}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 4}\left( {\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^{n + 1} {{1 \over {3r - 2}}}  - \sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^{n + 1}
 {{1 \over {3r + 2}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {12}}\left( {\sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^{n + 1} {{1 \over {r - 2/3}}}  - \sum\nolimits_{r = 1}^{n + 1}
 {{1 \over {r + 2/3}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {12}}\left( {\sum\nolimits_{r = 1/3}^{n + 1/3} {{1 \over r}}
  - \sum\nolimits_{r = 5/3}^{n + 5/3} {{1 \over r}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {12}}\left( {\psi (n + 1/3) - \psi (1/3) - \psi (n + 5/3) + \psi (5/3)} \right) \cr} 
$$
And in fact
$$
\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } S = {1 \over {12}}\left( {\psi (5/3) - \psi (1/3)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {12}}\left( {\left( {{{\pi \sqrt 3 } \over 6}
 - {{3\ln \left( 3 \right)} \over 2} - \gamma  + {3 \over 2}} \right)
 - \left( { - {{\pi \sqrt 3 } \over 6} - {{3\ln \left( 3 \right)} \over 2} - \gamma } \right)} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {12}}\left( {{{\pi \sqrt 3 } \over 3} + {3 \over 2}} \right) \cr} 
$$

Comment: I've not seen this approach before; so interesting to see this method spelt out. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, alas it is not well known as it deserves, because it is very neat and powerful. The renowned "Concrete Mathematics" provides an in deep treatment of the subject. I do suggest you to learn it.